# Is it possible to protect desktop applications cached files using bit locker

Tags: bitlocker

Can i create a partition on my harddrive and then put bilocker encryption on it and then some how setup my desktop windows application such that it can access that drive but at the same time no user or atleast no user without admin privileges is able to see the contents of that drive,

But my desktop application should be able to access the bitlicker drive data irrespective of which user has logged in the system,

I have already looked into bit locker and how it encrypts and decrypts files but no where i have found a bitlocker API for using it within some othet app. Now  I doubt if its even possible with bit locker to be used in this way

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to access bitlocker from another API. If there was another option, BitLocker security would have compromised. Microsoft has left no ways to open it. You may get some folder lock applications but they will also not allow you to set a program to access files within the folder when its locked. But you can try googling this, it will serve the purpose. Bitlocker is highly encrypted, in case you lose your password and key and there is no backup, there is almost impossible to access that part of your drive.

Hope that helps!